# How is one "Deemed Worthy", to acquire the Greatsword "Dawn"?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

> Ser [Arthur Dayne](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Arthur_Dayne) was a knight of House Dayne who bore the title
>   of **"Sword of the Morning" as he possessed the ancestral sword of House
>   Dayne, Dawn.** He was also a member of the Kingsguard under King Aerys
>   II Targaryen.

[image: ToJ]

> > The Sword of the Morning is a title bestowed upon the knight of House
> >     Dayne that bears Dawn, the ancestral longsword of the family. The title is not hereditary, automatically passed down to the current head
> >     of House Dayne. Rather, the sword Dawn is only held by a member of
> >     House Dayne who is considered worthy of the honor, after displaying
> >     immense skill at swordsmanship. Sometimes the head of House Dayne
> >     wields Dawn, but in some generations of the family it is held by a
> >     younger brother or cousin. In some generations, no member of the
> >     family is allowed to wield the sword at all, because it is deemed that
> >     none **have proven themselves worthy**. When a current "Sword of the
> >     Morning" dies, he does not pass Dawn down to his own children: **instead
> >     it is brought back to Starfall castle, to wait for a new "Sword of the
> >     Morning" to rise again** (which may take generations).
> >
> > According to George R.R. Martin, the sword Dawn remains at Starfall
> >     during the War of the Five Kings, because no new Sword of the Morning
> >     has yet risen since Arthur Dayne died.

Although the books get into the idea of House Dayne having/bestowing the Greatsword "Dawn" slightly better, the TV show still touches on Dawn, Arthur Dayne (Tower of Joy Sequence), and/or the title: *Sword of the Morning*, **but neither the books or tv series seems to explain what the SPECIFIC conditions are** for the passing of this sword. Only to say that it goes to one that is "deemed worthy" of it.

**Question:**

But whom specifically at Starfall or Members House Dayne gets to decide what "worthy" means, **but more importantly, what is the criteria for worthiness?**

---

**To Better Understand My Question:**

I'm interested in the philosophy and **methodology of philosophy** of House Dayne's inter-workings to help determine WHY this ritual has been preserved. Is there a council or a title given to those that decide whom and perhaps "when" someone is worthy of Dawn? Is Magic (visions) in conjunction to Religion (a belief in some desired outcome) used in this determination? Is there some kind of "test" or "long term" intent for the role of *Sword of the Morning(s)*?

Is there any specific instance I either overlooked or exists in other source materials to better understand these things. Any Help would be much appreciated, as I believe that

A: It enriches the story by adding to overall ASoIF/GOT philosophy.This then also helps establish themes.

B: Enhances the mythology/metaphysics ---> White Walkers, Cycle Cosmology, Reincarnation, Dawn Age/Age of Heroes & Biblical Allegory: Sword of the Morning + Starfell + Dawn = "Morning Star", The Dawn of a New Era) and *could provide a future "plot twist".

Comment: Can't help feeling that this might be more easily answered on SF&F. It's doubtful that the TV series has covered this in any depth...if at all.

Comment: I'd guess it's like Thor's Hammer...if you are worthy..it becomes obvious.

Comment: @Paulie_D Should I delete this then ask it over there then? I know it's not recomended when there are answers to delete Qs????

Comment: It won't let me delete--should I vote to close it then?

Comment: There's already answer with upvote, so you can't delete that easily. It's more or less on topic I guess, but in the future you may prefer to ask similar questions rather on SF&F where it's definitely on topic and there's better chance of good answer.

Comment: As far as question goes, its premise seems to be flawed, why should there be anything "specific"? It seems obvious that if there was a famous, noble knight and members of the House (especially those high ranking) thought he should get the sword the he gets it...

Comment: Because The Sword/Knighthood could deeper tie into the mythology--ie it may be more special then Valeryen steel--that fact that it is an "ancient" anncestriall sword that is specifically overlooked by house Dayne (ie: why is this the only house that conducts this ritual of a one of a kind sword?) could be relavent, if one of the main characters is "meant" to wield it and because it may relate to the history of White Walkers and/or The Age of Heroes --the words/phrase Dawn or Sword of the Morning, & Starfell could = "dawn of a new age" allegory to "morning star"

Comment: IMO Martin may have given us a tease of something important, by not telling the readers what's really behind it YET (and the TV series still chose to include some of it), but I also thought perhaps they may be more about this writen or stated somewhere than I think, so that is why I asked the Q!

Comment: He has been known to make remarks that the (for now) minor characters in the plot each have a role to play. So it might indeed become relevant in the future. (I think he said this responding to the show cutting Garlan and Willas Tyrell.

Answer (score 9):

The members of the House Dayne decide whether someone is worthy.

As spake Martin:

> - The same guy asked about the Daynes and the Sword of the Morning, asking how that title is decided. George said the Sword of the Morning is always a member of House Dayne, someone who is deemed worthy of wielding Dawn **as decided within the House**, that whoever it is would have to earn the right to wield it.
>   <sub>[US Signing Tour (Albuquerque, NM), November 29, 2005 So Spake Martin](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1395/) - emphasis mine</sub>

Since Arthur Dayne died during Robert's rebellion, nobody has been deemed worthy, so Dawn remains unused.

> The Daynes of Starfall are one of the most ancient houses in the Seven Kingdoms, though their fame largely rests on their ancestral sword, called Dawn, and the men who wielded it. Its origins are lost to legend, but it seems likely that the Daynes have carried it for thousands of years. Those who have had the honor of examining it say it looks like no Valyrian steel they know, being pale as milkglass but in all other respects it seems to share the properties of Valyrian blades, being incredibly strong and sharp.
>
> Though many houses have their heirloom swords, they mostly pass the blades down from lord to lord. Some, such as the Corbrays have done, may lend the blade to a son or brother for his lifetime, only to have it return to the lord. But that is not the way of House Dayne. The wielder of Dawn is always given the title of Sword of the Morning, and only a knight of House Dayne who is deemed worthy can carry it.
>
> For this reason, the Swords of the Morning are all famous throughout the Seven Kingdoms. There are boys who secretly dream of being a son of Starfall so they might claim that storied sword and its title. Most famous of all was Ser Arthur Dayne, the deadliest of King Aerys II's Kingsguard, who defeated the Kingswood Brotherhood and won renown in every tourney and mêlée. He died nobly with his sworn brothers at the end of Robert's Rebellion, after Lord Eddard Stark was said to have killed him in single combat. Lord Stark then returned Dawn to Starfall, and to Ser Arthur's kin, as a sign of respect.
> <sub>The World of Ice and Fire - Dorne: The Andals Arrive</sub>

In a Feast for Crows, one of the other Daynes makes a remark about Dawn:

> Ser Gerold [Dayne] went to one knee. The moonlight shone in his dark eyes as he studied the child coolly.
>
> "There was an Arthur Dayne," Myrcella said. "He was a knight of the Kingsguard in the days of Mad King Aerys."
>
> "He was the Sword of the Morning. He is dead."
>
> "Are you the Sword of the Morning now?"
>
> "No. Men call me Darkstar, and I am of the night."
>
> (...)
>
> As she led the princess to the fire, Arianne found Ser Gerold behind her. "My House goes back ten thousand years, unto the dawn of days," he complained. "Why is it that my cousin is the only Dayne that anyone remembers?"
>
> "He was a great knight," Ser Arys Oakheart put in.
>
> "He had a great sword," Darkstar said.
> <sub>The Queenmaker - a Feast for Crows</sub>

Comment: Thanks for explaining the "memebers" decide part! I upvoted you for that, but I'm still looking for something "deeper" in terms of how those members critique it (at any given time), because it is curious to me that there are times where they believe no one is worthy and I'm also curious if this is also about "purpose" and "fate" as well (Does house Dayne have a way to see the future and/or do they have specific belief system (religion) that leads them towards a specific definition or worthiness?

Comment: @DarthLocke given that this piece of information is already so obscure that it needed Word of God to say it, instead of it being in the books, I doubt there is much more information about it right now :(

Comment: `one of the other Daynes makes a remark about Dawn`, Dorkstar is a disgrace to the Dayne name. What he says about Arthur's skills being solely due to his sword is patently false. When Arthur Dayne fought the Smiling Knight, he gave Dawn to his opponent on his request and still won.  (But yes the Smiling Knight was already wounded but this should be evidence that Dayne wasn't afraid to be part with his sword)

Comment: @Aegon is that what happened? I thought the `then you shall have it` meant he stabbed the smiling knight with it?

Comment: [JAD is correct](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183037/did-arthur-dayne-give-dawn-to-the-smiling-knight)

Comment: @JAD Ya, I suspect there probably isn't much more there, but I don't have all of the source materials, such as The World of Ice and Fire and thought maybe there is some tidbit out there that hints a little stronger at something. Thanks though for what you could find!

Comment: @DarthLocke With [asearchoficeandfire](https://asearchoficeandfire.com/) you can search through all the books, including TWOIAF ;)